# Passing parameters to crystal reports in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I've been trying to get this to work for a while, and all the example code I've seen aren't quite doing what I'm doing.

I have a program that returns a pdf of a report that I pass a data table to. This works fine, except I would like to pass it a couple of other parameters (the date range of the table, stats etc) and I just can't get it to work. My code basically looks like this.

```
ReportDocument myDataReport = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
myDataReport.Load(@"C:\Layouts\Report.rpt");
ParameterField myParam = new ParameterField();
ParameterDiscreteValue myDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
myParam.ParameterFieldName = "MyParameter";
myDiscreteValue.Value = "Hello";
myParam.CurrentValues.Add(myDiscreteValue);
myDataReport.ParameterFields.Add(myParam);
myDataReport.SetDataSource(myDataTable);
Stream returnData = myDataReport.ExportToStream(PortableDocFormat);
myDataReport.Close();
return returnData;
```

I have added the parameter field in the rpt document in crystal, do I have to change anything in the xsd file in c#, or am I missing something completely different?

Many thanks, Andy.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

All that parameter code can be replaced with...

```
// Set datasource first
myDataReport.SetDataSource(...)
// Assign Paramters after set datasource
myDataReport.SetParameterValue("MyParameter", "Hello");
```

I can't remember if the order matters when setting the datasource and parameters. Maybe try setting the datasource first. The xsd/datasource has no relation to crystal parameters.

**UPDATE1**

SetParameterValue AFTER the datasource asignation
or you will recieve error "Missing parameter values."

Comment: Yep that was it! I think I tried that line before, but I had the datasource set in the wrong place as you pointed out. Works compeletly now, thanks!

Comment: @Andrew. Could you please tell me where did you put the call to the dataSource?

Comment: Put SetParameterValue AFTER the datasource asignation

Answer (score 4):

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();

TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
Tables CrTables;

string path = "C:/reportpath/report.rpt";
cryRpt.Load(path);

cryRpt.SetParameterValue("MyDate2", str2);
cryRpt.SetParameterValue("MyDate", str1);

crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "server";
crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DataBase";
crConnectionInfo.UserID = "user";
crConnectionInfo.Password = "password";

CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
{
    crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
    crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
}

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       //create object of crystal report.
        CrystalReport1 objRpt = new CrystalReport1();
        objRpt.SetDataSource(ds);
        ParameterFields pfield = new ParameterFields();
        ParameterField ptitle = new ParameterField();
        ParameterDiscreteValue pvalue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ptitle.ParameterFieldName = "date";
        pvalue.Value = txtcolor.Text;
        ptitle.CurrentValues.Add(pvalue);
        pfield.Add(ptitle);
        crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = pfield;
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Please explain what you have fixed or are suggesting. Just adding code is not much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

just do one thing and your code will run automatically set the data source first before adding parameters...

```
 crp rpt = new crp();
 rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
 rpt.SetParameterValue("p",p.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                rptTeacherTimeTable ttReport = new rptTeacherTimeTable();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = ObjclsT_TimeTable.GetTimeTableByClass(ClassID);

                objReport = ttReport;
                objReport.SetDataSource(dt);
                objReport.SetParameterValue("RTitle", "Class Time Table");
                objReport.SetParameterValue("STitle", "Teacher Time Table");
                reportViewer.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objReport;
                reportViewer.crystalReportViewer1.Show();
                reportViewer.Show();
```

Comment: Please explain!