# Integrating existing crystal report C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I externally created a Crystal Report that I now want to integrate into my C# application using Visual Studio. I added a new item(Crystal Report template) to my project and chose the "From an Existing Report" radio button. I then entered the path of where my report exists. The report then shows up, and the data appears when I click on the Main Report Preview button.

The report has a static parameter that I need to populate before displaying the report.

Being new to C# I am unsure how to

- Populate the parameter
- Cause the Report to appear

I did search for how to populate the parameter and this is the code I'm using.

```
CrystalReport1 g3 = new CrystalReport1();
g3.SetParameterValue("SupplierName", SupplierID);
g3.Refresh();
```

I don't get an error, but my report isn't showing up, so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: you need to supply the `g3.DataSource = ....`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to crystal reports in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589021/passing-parameters-to-crystal-reports-in-c-sharp)