# Filter data in crystal report using datetimepicker

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, datetimepicker

I'm working on a report in Crystal Reports C# windows application.i fetch the data from localhost server to crystal report. I have 2 datetimepicker in my form.

datetimepicker1 = dtpfrom

datetimepicker2 - dtpto

[image]

Crystalreport

[image]

Now I want that, when selecting some date in from and the to datetimepicker the between data is show in the crystal report please help me to solve i don't know how to start. i'm searching through googling i didn't get any thing about between data in datetimepicker show in crystal report. Any ideas?

Here my try:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyCon);
            CrystalReport1 objcr = new CrystalReport1();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from data where date>='" + DateTime.Parse(dtpfrom.Text) + "' and date<='" + DateTime.Parse(dtpto.Text) + "' ", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            objcr.SetDataSource(dt);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objcr;
            crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

But i'm getting an error

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException' occurred
>   in CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.dll
>
> Additional information: Failed to load database information.

On line:

```
objcr.SetDataSource(dt);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589021/passing-parameters-to-crystal-reports-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-date-to-date.htm

Comment: Its work on the report but Its not work on runtime. your answer is good one but me to filter data in the report on runtime use of datetimepicker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@divi

filter data in report using datetimepicker is not done for your coding

**Do the following:**

create a new parameter fromdate, todate in Field Explorer -> Parameter Field(Right Click)-> New
[image]

like this make todate also

[image]

then right click the report.

Select Report -> Selection Formula -> Record...

Do following

[image]

then click save and close button in that form.

**Know this:**

Right Click the report -> Database -> Set Datasource Location...

[image]

**Now Code**

```
 ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
            report.Load("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\CrystalReport1.rpt");

            TableLogOnInfo Table = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo Connection = new ConnectionInfo();
            Tables Tables;

            ParameterFieldDefinitions Parameters;
            ParameterFieldDefinition Parameter;
            ParameterValues Values = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue DiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            DiscreteValue.Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
            Parameters = report.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            Parameter = Parameters["fromdate"];
            Values = Parameter.CurrentValues;

            Values.Clear();
            Values.Add(DiscreteValue);
            Parameter.ApplyCurrentValues(Values);

            DiscreteValue.Value = dateTimePicker2.Text;
            Parameters = report.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            Parameter = Parameters["todate"];
            Values = Parameter.CurrentValues;

            Values.Add(DiscreteValue);
            Parameter.ApplyCurrentValues(Values);

            Connection.ServerName = "Your servername in Set Datasource Location";
            Connection.DatabaseName = "Your databasename in Set Datasource Location";
            Connection.UserID = "your username";
            Connection.Password = "your password";

            Tables = report.Database.Tables;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in Tables)
            {
                Table = table.LogOnInfo;
                Table.ConnectionInfo = Connection;
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(Table);
            }

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Hope This helps to solve your problem.