# How to display crystal report by date parameters selected from Win Forms in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

- my report comes out blank, when I define date to date parameter.
- my report source is XML file.

**Records Report**

[image]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        TR = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Records>().ElementAt(0);
        try
        {
            ds = new DataSet2();
            dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dt = ConvertDGVtoDataTable(TR.recordsTableDataGridView);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ds.WriteXmlSchema("RecordsReport.xml");

        try
        {

            ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;
            ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
            ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            crParameterFieldDefinitions = treport1.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["fromDate"];
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

            crParameterValues.Clear();
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
            crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
            crParameterFieldDefinitions = treport1.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["toDate"];
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
            crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

        // Report Form.
        TReportDisplay TRD = new TReportDisplay();
        Treport treport1 = new Treport();

            TRD.crystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = treport1;
            treport1.SetDataSource(ds);
            TRD.Show();
            TRD.crystalReportViewer2.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); };
    }

    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
}
```

My Report has two parameters, **fromDate** and **toDate**, both defined as **Date Time**, 
Discreet Values.
[image]

my selection record formula is as follows:

[image]

If I remove this formula, then the report will display everything, but if I enter this formula then the report comes out blank.

**Solved:** In my case I won't use Database values as "Arthi has present here" 
[Filter data in crystal report using datetimepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391112/filter-data-in-crystal-report-using-datetimepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dateTimePicker1.Value, try the below:

```
crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
```

See this - [Filter data in crystal report using datetimepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391112/filter-data-in-crystal-report-using-datetimepicker)

Comment: still blank, if I remove this formula, it will display everything, as soon as I put this it won't display a thing. `{Table1.Date} in '"{?fromDate}"' to '"{?toDate}"'`

Comment: I think, the problem is with the parameters. Seems it doesn't get passed.

Comment: it seems like that, not sure why this is happening.. stucked here from past 3 days.

Comment: Edited the post and given a link to follow.

Comment: Thank you, it works, from the link you gave me, it's a bit modified, as I do not have database, I'm not using database code that "arthi" gave in that code. 

there is only 1 problem, when the report is opened, it asks me for dates  , from and to, I already tell him the date before generating, it should not ask again.