# Pass parameter value from mvc controller to crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Good day.

It may be a noob question but ow do you pass a parameter from controller to crystal reports? I am kinda new when it comes to crystal reports.

**Controller**

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "Mtop.rpt"));
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=test.tayabas.gov.ph;initial catalog=iVehicles;User ID=sa;Password=TEST@dm!n!@#$%;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_vwFranchiseList");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@franchiseid", franchiseid);
rd.SetParameterValue("@Name", Tname);
rd.SetParameterValue("@Position", TPosition);

cmd.Connection = cn;
sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

I have a crystal report `Mtop.rpt`. Inside it I created two new parameters named, `Name` and `Position`. But when I try the code above, I receive an error

> Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

What am I doing wrong here? Is there an easier way to pass a value from controller to crystal reports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try without "@": rd.SetParameterValue("Name", Tname);
rd.SetParameterValue("Position", TPosition);

Comment: @heringer Tried it sir. still not working

Comment: Try SetDataSource before SetParameterValue as sugested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589021/passing-parameters-to-crystal-reports-in-c-sharp). If it does not solve the problem, check the details in that post and compare to your code. Check if you are passing null too.

Comment: @heringer Ok. I managed to make it work but not adding anymore parameters. I just added a new variable at my stored procedure then placed the values in a var in my controller.  I then used the cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue to add the value then got it in my crystal reports. Since only one value is posted to my report, there is no worry in multiple values posting.