# Record Selection formula using multipplie AND

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I would like filter report with from and to dates, team id and status. For example:

Dates like "10.12.2019" to "20.12.2019"

Team like "LM2213"

Status like "Active"

I am using vb.net with crystal report

```
crv1.SelectionFormula = "{table.sdate} IN DateValue (" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy,MM,dd") & " ) TO DateValue (" & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy,MM,dd") & " )and {table.status}='" & cmb_status.SelectedItem & "' and {table.trip_id}='" & cmb_team.Text & "'"

crv1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: What is your question here; you haven't asked one. Why does this have to do with SQL Server, when the only thing we have is some VB.net code.

Comment: There are 2 parts, first define a parameter in crystal report and give selectionformula as you are written. Second from vb.net code pass parameter value to crystal report. Where are you stuck. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589021/passing-parameters-to-crystal-reports-in-c-sharp

Comment: Check this also:- http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_parameter_string.htm